# Laravel:Não consigo Realizar Download de um arquivo

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, download

Já tentei segui vários tutoriais e pesquisei problemas similares aqui no stack,em relação ao download de arquivos,porém sem sucesso ,anteriormente eu pegava o id do arquivo e ele era passado como parâmetro e não retornava nada.Agora finalmente consigo localizar o arquivo pelo nome porém o download não realizado,ele baixa um html e dá erro no servidor, além do que ele não pega o formato do arquivo.

---

Routes

```php
Route::get('/download/{fileId}', 'ArquivosController@download');
```

Controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Arquivos;
use FontLib\Table\Type\name;
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class ArquivosController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('templates')->with('arquivos', Arquivos::get());
    }
//Adicionar
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nome' => 'required',

        ]);

        $arquivo = new Arquivos;
        if (is_null($request->input('nome'))) {
            $arquivo->nome = str_replace('.' . $request->arquivo->extension(), '', $request->arquivo->getClientOriginalName());
        } else {
            $arquivo->nome = $request->input('nome');
        }
        $arquivo->tamanho = $request->arquivo->getClientSize();
        $arquivo->tipo = $request->arquivo->extension();
        $arquivo->caminho = 'files/' . $request->arquivo->storeAs('', str_slug($arquivo->nome) . '.' . $arquivo->tipo, 'upl_arquivos');
        $arquivo->save();
        return back()->with("Upload do arquivo '{$arquivo->nome}' realizado com sucesso.");
    }

    //Excluir
    public function destroy(Request $request) {
       Arquivos::destroy($request->id);
        return redirect('/templates');
    }

    //Download
    public function download()
    {
        $downloads = Arquivos::saved('TEMPLATE')->get();
        return view('/templates',compact('downloads'));



    }





}
```

Index

```
  <div class="panel-footer" style="padding:0px;">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                                <th>Tipo</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            @foreach($arquivos as $arquivo)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$arquivo->nome}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$arquivo->tipo}}</td>


                                    <td>  <a href="download/{{$arquivo->nome}}" download="{{$arquivo->nome}}" >Download</a></td>
                                    <td><a href = 'delete/{{ $arquivo->id }}' >Delete</a></td>

                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Consigo Realizar o Upload e a deleção normalmente,não consigo identificar o erro no downlaod,pois ainda sou iniciante no framework(v.5.3).

Comment: O método está errado pois deveria ter um pra cada operação.

Comment: @Virgilio Novic não entendi o que você quis dizer,com deveria ter um para cada operação

Comment: Uma você mostra a view a outra você executa os comandos para download e você fez um método para tudo...

Comment: Você na rota pede fileid e na função não tem a variável com mesmo nome

Answer (score -2):

Tente algo como

```
public function getDownload()
{

    $file= public_path(). "/download/info.pdf";

    $headers = array(
              'Content-Type: application/pdf',
            );

    return Response::download($file, 'filename.pdf', $headers);
}
```